# Escape Sentence Sed System() C

Tags: c, sed, archlinux

I have to use this Linux command in a terminal:

```
sed -i "/\[multilib\]/,/Include/"'s/#//' /etc/pacman.conf
```

What it does is uncomment the lines

```
#[multilib][...]
#Include[...]
```

The trick is that I'm trying to use this in a system() function in C. So I was ending up with this code:

```
system("sed -i "/\[multilib\]/,/Include/"'s/#//' /etc/pacman.conf");
```

But something went wrong so I decided to use an echo to see the ouput:

```
system("echo 'sed -i "/\[multilib\]/,/Include/"'s/#//' /etc/pacman.conf'");
```

I saw that the ouput wasn't exactly what I wanted to use and some of you (thanks guys) told me that there were escape sentences to use, so I did some changes:

```
system("echo 'sed -i \"/\\[multilib\\]/,/Include/\"\'s/#//\' /etc/pacman.conf'");
```

Now the ouput in xterm is:

```
sed -i "/[\multilib\]/,/Include/"s/#// pacman.conf
```

As you can see, the problem is:

```
s/#//
```

Which lacks of his ' ' marks. Even though I used an escape sentence.

**EDIT 3:** Explanations from comments worked. An echo without the system() in a linux terminal showed that xterm doesn't get the ' ' marks either despite of the escape sentence. So it worked for the escape sentence which was my question.

**EDIT 4:** no need for a new thread it worked now... Don't tell me why I've just rewritten the thing.

Comment: It could be me but your question seems really unclear.  Could you post the actual output that you're getting and how that differs from what you expect?

Comment: @david-hoelzer will edit.

Comment: Are you just asking how to put " marks in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a `"` in a string, write it as `\"`. This is called an *escape sequence*.

```
system("echo '\"/[multilib]/,/Include/\" 's/#//' /etc/pacman.conf'");
```

Comment: Thanks @immibis, now I wanted to escape the ' ' but it's not working with \'s/#//\'. Any workaround ?

Comment: @Gradiuss If you want to put a \ in a string, write it as \\

Comment: I actually wanted to put the ' ' marks. But it seems that it gets ignored. I don't think this is the system() command in fault butit's kinda weird because I can wrtie it down and compile it but the echo output without the ' ' marks.

Comment: @Gradiuss: You're invoking `echo` instead of `sed`; maybe you need to change that?  `system("sed '/\\[multilib]/,/Include/ s/#//' /etc/pacman.conf");` might be what you're after.  Note that the `/[multilib]/` pattern looks for a line containing one instance of any of the characters `b`, `i`, `l`, `m`, `t`, `u`; as I wrote it, it makes `sed` look for a line containing the word `multilib` enclosed in square brackets — quite a different meaning.  When you're sure the `sed` script does what you need, you can consider overwriting the configuration file — but don't do it before you're sure it is OK.

Comment: @Gradiuss There is no problem with putting ' in a string in C - you write `'`, you get `'`. If you wanted the string to contain `\'`, which is what I thought you meant, then you'd have to write `\\'`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler : it was for the purpose of testing the output, but I'm now testing with pacman.conf (and not /etc/pacman.conf otherwise good bye upgrades !). Thanks for the explication and to answer this is the behavior I expect : I want to uncomment the lines [mulitilib] and not [multilib-testing] and Include[...] that's why.

Comment: Oops, okay some changes appear. See EDIT 1.

Comment: @Gradiuss Do you know how shell commands work, and why the 's are there, and what they do?

Comment: @Gradiuss: OK.  You can replace my `sed` with `echo` and see what you get.  The backslash (double backslash in the C source code) before the square bracket is important.  I can't help but feel that you'd be better of writing a shell script containing the `sed` command you want to run, and then simply running that script from `system()` in C (assuming you need to do this from C code at all).  I'm glad you're testing on a copy of the configuration file — it's only sensible, but not necessarily something people think of until after they've been burned by not thinking of it.

Comment: @Gradiuss Hint: type `echo '"/[multilib]/,/Include/" 's/#//' /etc/pacman.conf'` in your shell and you'll get the same result - this is nothing to do with C.

Comment: IMO, the single quotes are there to ensure that the double quotes ensure that if `echo` is replaced by `sed`, `sed` will complain about syntax errors.

Comment: Okay explaination worked, this is a Linux issue now but thanks a lot everything you said was correct it just that an echo without the system() indicated that it doesn't get the ' ' marks either so i'll just open another thread.